# Test grouped cells in ag-grid react with testing-library

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, react-testing-library, ag-grid-react, testing-library

I am having trouble testing grouped cells in ag-grid react with React-testing-library.

My Grid:

```js
const MyGrid = props => {
  const rowData = [
    {
      model: 'samsung',
      name: 'My TV',
      room: 'living room',
      connectedDevices: [
        {
          type: 'receiver',
          deviceName: 'My Receiver',
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  const detailCellRendererParams = { 
    detailGridOptions: { 
      columnDefs: [
        {field: 'type'},
        {field: 'deviceName'},
      ],
      // suppressColumnVirtualisation: true,
    },
    getDetailRowData: params => params.successCallback(params.node.data.connectedDevices),
  };


  return (
    <AgGridReact
      colDefs={[
        {field: model},
        {field: name, cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer'},
        {field: room},
      ]}
      rowData={rowData} 
      masterDetail={true} 
      detailCellRendererParams={detailCellRendererParams}
      suppressColumnVirtualisation={true}
    />
  );
}
```

Then in my test

```js
describe('Test MyGrid', () => {
  it('Should display the connected device in the detail grid', async () => {
    const groupCell = await screen.findByText('My TV');
    user.dblClick(groupCell);
    // user.click(document.getElementsByClass('ag-icon-tree-closed')[0]);
    
    const connectedDevices = [
      {
        type: 'receiver',
        deviceName: 'My Receiver',
      }
    ];

    for (const d of connectedDevices) {
      expect(screen.getByText(d.name)).toBeInTheDocument();
    }
  });
});
```

However the test doesn't even make it past the `await screen.findByText('My TV')`. When I view the html in the testing playground using `screen.logTestingPlaygroundUrl()`. The column header is present but none of the actual gridcell elements for the name column can be found. I experimented with suppressing the column virtualization of the detail grid after viewing this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63969843/how-can-i-test-the-content-in-ag-grid-using-testing-library), but that didn't work. Has anyone out there found success testing grouped grid in ag-grid?